# How can we determine the numbers $k_1$ and $k_2$ ?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}1+ci & w_1 \\ 2+i & z_2\end{pmatrix}$ with $c\in \mathbb{R}$ is hermitian, of order $1$ and the vector $(k_1, k_2)\in \mathbb{C}^2$ with $k_2$ positive real number, belongs to the orthogonal complement of the row space of $A$ and has norm $\sqrt{3}$.

How can we determine the numbers $k_1$ and $k_2$ ?

$$$$

We know that $A$ is hermitian, so it is equal to its own conjugate transpose. So we have $A=\overline{A^T}$, i.e. $$\begin{pmatrix}1+ci & w_1 \\ 2+i & z_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1-ci & 2-i \\ \overline{w_1} & \overline{z_2}\end{pmatrix}$$ From that we get that $c=0$, $w_1=2-i$ and $z_2=\overline{z_2}$ and so $z_2$ is real.

Are the information correct so far?

Then we have that $A$ has the order 1, that means that $A^1=I_2$, or not?

Now we have to calculate the orthogonal complement of the row space of $A$, or not? How can we do that?

The last information is that the vector $(k_1, k_2)$ has the norm $\sqrt{3}$ and so we get $\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}=\sqrt{3}\Rightarrow k_1^2+k_2^2=3$, right?

Comment: I agree with the form of $A$ you have so far. You may try to prove it yourself, but the orthogonal complement of the row space of $A$ is the kernel of $A$. I don't know what does it mean that the order of the matrix is 1.

Comment: We have the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2-i \\ 2+i & z_2\end{pmatrix}$. The kernel is $$\ker (A)=\left \{x \in \mathbb{C}^2 \mid Ax=0\right \}=\left \{x \in \mathbb{C}^2\middle | \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2-i \\ 2+i & z_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\right \}=\left \{x \in \mathbb{C}^2\middle | \begin{pmatrix}x_1+(2-i)x_2 \\ (2+i)x_1+z_2x_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\right \}$$ @Javi

Comment: So we get $$x_1+(2-i)x_2=0\Rightarrow x_1=-(2-i)x_2$$ and $$(2+i)x_1+z_2x_2=0\Rightarrow (2+i)\left (-(2-i)x_2\right )+z_2x_2=0\Rightarrow -5x_2+z_2x_2=0\Rightarrow (-5+z_2)x_2=0$$ Is everything correct so far? What do we get from the second equation and how is then the kernel defined? @Javi

Comment: so it looks like (0,0) is a vector in the kernel of $A$, but could it be the only vector? (no) why not? what is the value of $z_2$ that makes other vectors exist in the kernel? and finally, which vector or vectors in the kernel satisfy the requirements given for $(k_1,k_2)$?

Comment: If $z_2=5$ there are infinitely many vectors in the kernel and if $z_2\neq 5$ the kernel consists only of the vector$(0,0)$, right? Why do we have to consider that there must be also other vectors besides the zero vector? @Javi

Comment: well that is what I've just asked you... read the statement of the problem, it actually says (with other words) that there is a non-zero vector in the kernel, which one is it?

Comment: Ah because $k_2$ is positive, right? So the kernel is $$\left \{x \in \mathbb{C}^2\middle | \begin{pmatrix}-(2-i)x_2 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}\right \}=\left \{x_2\begin{pmatrix}-(2-i) \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\middle | x_2\in \mathbb{C}\right \}$$ So $k_1=-2+i$ and $k_2=1$, right? @Javi

Comment: because $k_2$ is positive, yes, or also because the norm of $(k_1, k_2)$ is not zero. I agree with the expression you got for the kernel, but not with your selection of $(k_1, k_2)$. You indeed selected a vector of the kernel, but not one with norm $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: Ah yes! So we have $(k_1, k_2)=\left (-(2-i)x_2, x_2\right )$. We are looking for $x_3$ so that the norm is $\sqrt{3}$: $$\sqrt{\left (-(2-i)x_2\right )^2+x_2^2}=\sqrt{3}\Rightarrow (2-i)^2x_2^2+x_2^2=3\Rightarrow \left (4-4i-1+1\right )x_2^2=3 \\ \Rightarrow \left (4-4i\right )x_2^2=3 \Rightarrow x_2^2=\frac{3}{4-4i} \Rightarrow x_2=\sqrt{\frac{3}{4-4i}}$$ But then is $k_2$ complex, or not? @Javi

Comment: you are mistaking the calculation of the norm with complex components. It should be $\sqrt{(|-(2-i)| x_2)^2 + x_2^2}$

Comment: for clarification: remember that $\|v\|^2 = v^H v$

Comment: Oh ok! So we  have the following: $$\sqrt{\left (|-(2-i|)x_2\right )^2+x_2^2}=\sqrt{3}\Rightarrow |-2+i|^2x_2^2+x_2^2=3 \\ \Rightarrow (4-1)x_2^2+x_2^2=3\Rightarrow 3x_2^2+x_2^2=3\Rightarrow 4x_2^2=3 \Rightarrow x_2^2=\frac{3}{4} \\ \Rightarrow x_2=\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$  or not? @Javi

Comment: yes, except for the fact that $|-2+i|^2=4+1=5$. Look for the calculation of the modulus of complex numbers. Besides that, your answer is ok, just keep in mind that you have 2 solutions for $x_2$ to that equation, you just kept the positive one, which in this case is the right thing to do because the other yields a negative value of $k_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to put the information in all the comments together:

You may make use of the fact that the orthogonal complement of the row space of $A$ is the kernel of $A$ (that is easy to prove.)

Then, $z_2$ may be determined, keeping in mind that there is at least 1 non-zero vector in the kernel of $A$ (which vector?). Then find what the kernel is.

Finally, you may find one (or more maybe?) vectors $(k_1, k_2)$ in the kernel of $A$ which satisfies the requirements given for $k_2$ and $\|(k_1, k_2)\|$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! :-)